# how to copy data from internal stage to snowflake table continuously?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have loaded data in internal/names stage in snowflake and now want to copy data from internal stage to snowflake table continuously. I read that continuous load via snowpipe is supported only for external stage and not for internal stage. So what is the way to load data from internal stage to snowflake table continuously?

Thanks in advance.
Amrita

Comment: How are you planning to copy the data into the internal stage continuously?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Snowpipe but you'll need to call the [REST API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest-load.html) for Snowpipe to load the data.

Have you considered simply running a `COPY` statement immediately after you run the `PUT` command to get the file into the table?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Tasks and Schedule it for every 5 mins.

```
// Task DDL
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK MASTER_TASK
    WAREHOUSE  = LOAD_WH
    SCHEDULE = '5 MINUTE'
    AS 
    COPY INTO STAGE_TABLE
    FROM @STAGE;
```

You can always change the frequency based on your requirement. Refer to this [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html)
For External Stage, please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252579/how-to-purge-stage-or-delete-files-from-stage-when-using-snowpipe/67252580#67252580)