# How to PURGE Stage or delete files from Stage when using SNOWPIPE?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake provides Snowpipe to Copy data into a Table as soon as it is available in a Stage, but it misses the option of Purge.
Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to achieve Purge in case of Snowpipe but it can be achieved through the combination of ***Snowpipe***, ***Stream*** and ***Task***

Let's assume we have our Data files to be loaded residing in GCS Bucket

**Step 1:** Create a Snowpipe on Snowflake with an External stage
Refer to this [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-gcs.html)

```
// Create a Staging Table
CREATE TABLE SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_STAGE_TABLE (COL1 STRING);

// Create Destination Table
CREATE TABLE SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_DESTINATION_TABLE (COL1 STRING);

// Create an External Stage
CREATE STAGE SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_STAGE
  URL='gcs://bucket/files/'
  STORAGE_INTEGRATION = '<STORAGE_INTEGRATION>'; 

// Create Snowpipe
CREATE PIPE SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_Pipe
  AUTO_INGEST = true
  INTEGRATION = '<NOTIFICATION_INTEGRATION>'
  AS
  COPY INTO SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_STAGE_TABLE
  FROM @SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_STAGE;
```

**Step 2:** Create Stream on Table `GCP_STAGE_TABLE`

A stream records data manipulation language (DML) changes made to a table, including information about inserts, updates, and deletes.
Refer to this [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stream.html)

```
// Create Stream in APPEND_ONLY Mode since we are concerned with INSERTS only

CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.RESPONSES_STREAM
  ON TABLE SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_STAGE_TABLE
  APPEND_ONLY = TRUE;
```

Now, whenever some data is uploaded on the GCS Bucket, `GCP_STAGE_TABLE` is populated by Snowpipe and so is our Stream `RESPONSES_STREAM`

`RESPONSES_STREAM` Would look like this

| COL1 | METADATA$ACTION | METADATA$ISUPDATE | METADATA$ROW_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MOHAMMED | INSERT | FALSE | kjee941e66d4ca4hhh1e2b8ddba12c9c905a829 |
| TURKY | INSERT | FALSE | b7c5uytba6c1jhhfb6e9d85e3d3cfd7249192b0d8 |

Since the Stream has `APPEND_ONLY` Mode, we will only see `INSERT` in `METADATA$ACTION`

**Step 3:** Create a Procedure to `PURGE` the stage and Populate `GCP_DESTINATION_TABLE`

```
// Create a Procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE Load_Data()
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS 
    $$
    var purgeStage = `REMOVE @SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_STAGE`; 
    var populateTable = `INSERT INTO SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_DESTINATION_TABLE
                         SELECT * FROM RESPONSES_STREAM`;
    try {
        snowflake.execute ( {sqlText: purgeStage} );
        snowflake.execute ( {sqlText: populateTable} );
        return "Succeeded."; 
        }
    catch (err)  {
        return "Failed: " + err; 
        }
    $$
```

The above Procedure uses `REMOVE` command to purge the Stage and Populates the Table `GCP_DESTINATION_TABLE`.
Populating the Table `GCP_DESTINATION_TABLE` from the Stream `RESPONSES_STREAM` Clears the Stream.

**Step 4:** Create a Task to call the Procedure `Load_Data()`
Refer to this [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html)

We create a Task with a 5 mins interval which 1st checks the Stream `RESPONSES_STREAM` for any Data loaded to `GCP_STAGE_TABLE`, if True, executes a Procedure `Load_Data()`

```
// Task DDL
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK MASTER_TASK
    WAREHOUSE  = LOAD_WH
    SCHEDULE = '5 MINUTE'
    WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.RESPONSES_STREAM') //Checks the stream for Data
AS 
    CALL Load_Data();
```

`SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('RESPONSES_STREAM')` evaluates to True when Data is loaded to `GCP_STAGE_TABLE`, this then makes the Task execute the Procedure call.

Even though the Procedure is not called every 5 mins, it's worth noting that `WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('RESPONSES_STREAM')` does consume a minute Compute resource, to reduce this, the frequency can be changed from 5 mins to a greater duration.

To make this an ELT task, Procedure can have some transformation logic and a Tree of Tasks can be made.

Note:

1. `REMOVE` is not officially supported for External stages but it still worked for GCS Bucket for me.
2. Let me know if it works for you in the case of AWS S3 and Azure.

Comment: Doesn't 'REMOVE @SNOWPIPE_DB.PUBLIC.GCP_STAGE' remove all files from the stage? What if files have been written to the stage but not yet pulled into the staging table by the pipe when the task runs? Do you risk losing files this way?

Comment: The Remove command can actually be skipped since it was put there to remove files from the GCP Bucket, to reduce storage costs